# Problem with positioning using view width and height

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, position, responsive

I was trying to solve a React challenge. The challenge is when you click somewhere on the screen, a circle appears where you clicked. Also you have a redo and undo button. The problem happened with restrictions which are:

1. The circles must be responsive, so they change their size when the screen width changes (the smaller width, the smaller circle).
2. A circle must be created where the cursor was, so the cursor was in the center of the circle with any screen width.
3. When you click close to the undo/redo buttons or borders the 2nd rule is skipped, cause you need the circle to be fully inside the screen.

This is how it's supposed to look like:
[image: right version]

I solved the first with the width and height equal to the same value in vw.
I also solved the second subtracting a half of the circle's width from the position.
But with the last one I got problems on top and bottom borders. The circles move when the screen width changes.

Circles at the top and bottom are supposed to be sticked to buttons and bottom border respectively, but they aren't.
[image: my version]

Here's my code:

**App.tsx**

```js
export interface IPoint {
    x: number
    y: number
    size: number
    color: string
}

const pointSize = 5

export const App: FC = () => {
    const [points, setPoints] = useState<IPoint[]>([])

    const controlsRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    const handlePlacePoint = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        const offsetX = pointSize / 2
        const offsetY = pointSize / 2
        let x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 100
        let y = (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 100

        const controlsHeight =
            (controlsRef.current?.offsetHeight! / window.innerHeight) * 100

        if (x <= offsetX) {
            x = offsetX
        } else if (x >= 100 - offsetX) {
            x = 100 - offsetX
        }

        if (y <= controlsHeight + offsetY) {
            y = controlsHeight + offsetY
        } else if (y >= 100 - offsetY) {
            y = 100 - offsetY
        }

        const newPoint: IPoint = {
            x,
            y,
            color: generateColor(),
            size: pointSize
        }

        setPoints([...points, newPoint])
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <div className='controls' ref={controlsRef}>
                <button>Undo ↺</button>
                <button>Redo ↻</button>
            </div>
            <div
                className='points-panel'
                onClick={handlePlacePoint}
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#8b3ae0' }}
            >
                {points.map(point => (
                    <Point key={Math.random()} {...point} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

**Point.tsx**

```js
export const Point: FC<IPoint> = ({ x, y, size, color }) => {
    return (
        <div
            className='point'
            style={{
                backgroundColor: color,
                top: `calc(${y}vh - ${size / 2}vw)`,
                left: `calc(${x}vw - ${size / 2}vw)`,
                width: `${size}vw`,
                height: `${size}vw`
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

**App.css**

```css
.controls {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 5vh;
    display: flex;
}

.controls button {
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.pointsPanel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.point {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

**index.css**

```css
html,
body, 
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tried a lot of different ways, but I think I'm missing that the Point top value which is in vh is subtracted by value in vw. I don't know how to change it and not to break what already works. Could you please tell me how to fix it so it works with all 3 requirements? Or maybe there is more clean approach?

Comment: Point 1 doesn't mean anything..,? Circles are round by definition, that's not optional, and "responsive" without an explanation of what is meant by that, doesn't tell you anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've over-complicating things by ignoring that React is still just JavaScript, and is running in a browser with full CSS support. A bunch of what you need can be done much simpler by using native JS functions, and relying on CSS to place things:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Circle from "./Circle.jsx";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const field = useRef();
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([]);

  const placeCircle = e => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent;
    const { width, height } = field.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    points.push({
      id: Date.now(),
      x: offsetX / width,
      y: offsetY / height,
    });
    setPoints(points);
  };

  const circles = points.map(p => <Circle key={p.id} {...p} />);

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='panel' onClick={placeCircle} ref={field}>
        {circles}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Native click events have an `offsetX` and `offsetY`, which is exactly the thing you need here to get the click position *inside* of your div. So we use `event.nativeEvent` to get those, and then to turn them from coordinates into percentages, we just divide them by the width and height of the parent div. Something that again is trivial in plain JS, using the `getBoundingClientRect()` function that every HTML element has.

Then we define our `Circle` as a really, really dumb thing:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./Circle.css";

export default function Circle(props) {
  const sizing = {
    "--x": props.x,
    "--y": props.y,
    "--size": props.size ?? "1em",
  };
  return <div className="circle" style={sizing}/>;
}
```

So yeah, that does nothing, it just forwards the values we need as CSS variables, we're not going to make JS do *anything* here. Instead, we make the browser do it for us:

```
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% * var(--y));
  left: calc(100% * var(--x));
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  margin-top: calc(var(--size) / -2);
  margin-left: calc(var(--size) / -2);
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

And we're done. If we need different background colors, same deal: make the circle set a `--bg-color` var with a random color, and add `background-color: var(--bg-color);` to your CSS. Never set actual style properties using the `style` attribute, it just makes styling much harder to debug than it needs to be. Use classes, and then have those classes do what they need to using CSS variables.

And of course, you can give CSS variables default values on the CSS side so that it works even when React hasn't loaded.

(And finally: there's kinda no point in loading your CSS on the JS side. Something like sass lets you write super nice, nested CSS, which can you turn into its own single CSS file that you then load in your index.html - The more you make the browser do what it's best at, the faster things run, and the easier they get to maintain)